# Having problems with local database in VS2012 using MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I added a local database to my project, added tables and such. And it works fine. However, I wanted one of my friends to test the application, and whenever the database is supposed to be used, he gets an error: [image]

I read online about this, and there doesn't seem to be any solutions that worked for me.

What I've tried: Open data sources, add new data source, and use my database.
Nothing seems to work.

Whenever I copy the `bin/debug/` folder to my other computer, I get the same error.
I also tried publishing the app, and everytime I install it on another PC, same error.

EDIT: My connection string:

`@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Name\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"`

Comment below if any more information is needed.

Comment: its a db connection problem. you need to check if you are able to connect through sql studio. there is a very good site on connection string that could help you http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Most likely it is not the fault of your code. By default remote connections to SQL Server are blocked. You may need to configure the server itself http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

Comment: This is my connection string: `const string connStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Name\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";`

Comment: Did you install SQL server LocalDB on your friends computer?  Also, I note that the connection string is pointing into your own personal user folder, I hope you're configuring things more suitably in your deployment.

Comment: Thanks @ErikFunkenbusch , I added SQL LocalDB in the application prerequisites. And changed the connection string to :`@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"` And now it works perfectly. Add this info in a answer, I'd be willing to accept.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `AttachDbFileName`. Here's why: when you and your friend connect to "the database" with your own applications, you actually get two different copies of the database. So he will add a row and you won't see it and vice-versa. Take a backup of your database and restore it *to the instance* and stop using the `AttachDbfileName` "feature"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me was first of all changing the connection string to `@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"` NOTE: The fire directory is changed with `|DataDirectory|`

And then taking [Erik Funkenbusch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61164/erik-funkenbusch)'s comment in consideration I had to install SQL server LocalDB Express on the target's computer. I did this by adding LocalDB in the application prerequisites prior to publishing.

Also,

[Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) suggested to remove `AttachDbFileName` -- his explanation:

> You really shouldn't be using AttachDbFileName. Here's why: when you and your friend connect to "the database" with your own applications, you actually get two different copies of the database. So he will add a row and you won't see it and vice-versa. Take a backup of your database and restore it to the instance and stop using the AttachDbfileName "feature"...